# Convert Onclick to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

```
for(var i=1;i<=s;i++){if(e[r]<0&&n<=0)
{n=Math.abs(e[r])-1;r++}
else if(n>0){n--}else{t=e[r];r++}
var o=document.createElement("div");
o.style.height=t+"px";o.className="thumbnail";
o.id="thumb"+i;
o.setAttribute("onclick","Viewer.goToPage("+i+");");
```

I'm trying to convert onclick into addEventListener due to CSP restrictions in Firefox OS but not getting success.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
    if (e[r] < 0 && n <= 0) {
        n = Math.abs(e[r]) - 1;
        r++
    } else if (n > 0) {
        n--
    } else {
        t = e[r];
        r++
    }
    var o = document.createElement("div");
    o.style.height = t + "px";
    o.className = "thumbnail";
    o.id = "thumb" + i;
    (function(j, elem) {
        elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
            Viewer.goToPage(j);
        }, false);
    }(i, o));
}
```

You'll have to capture the value of the iterator in an IIFE to make it persist in the callback for addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

You can use *addEventListener* for this, however I don't see any benefit over direct property assignment (based on adeneo's code):

```
o.onclick = (function(pageNum) {
  return function() {
    Viewer.goToPage(pageNum);
  };
}(i));

// Presumably o is added to the document before the next iteration
```

One benefit of this approach is that you can remove the listener later by assigning a new value to the element's *onclick* property, or add additional listeners using *addEventListener* (or equivalent).

If *addEventListener* is used to add an "anonymous" function, there's no easy way to remove it later.

And it's good to avoid *setAttribute* for attaching handlers as it's inconsistent across browsers. Directly setting the property is supported by every browser back to IE and NN version 3 or earlier.